# Event for Fragment restoring from BackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I attach SessionFragment from SpeakerFragment with code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new SessionFragment(session))
                .addToBackStack("session")
                .commit();
```

In SessionFragment (in OnAttach()) I change ActionBar title to Session title.

When return back from SessionFragment, I want change ActionBar title to Speaker name. How can I do that?

OnStart(), OnResume(), onAttach() not calling.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener.html or this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onHiddenChanged(boolean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just added a fragment to the container without detaching or removing the previous one, try replace instead and set your ActionBar title in `OnActivityCreated()`

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, new SessionFragment(session))
        .addToBackStack("session")
        .commit();
```

Another note, you shouldn't use a non-empty Constructor for Fragments, as the framework will only call the empty constructor when restoring a fragment e.g. after idling, background etc.
Instead session's class should implement parcelable, and should be passed as fragment argument using `fragment.setArguments()`.